# Does `USING (column)` provide any memory advantage over an an explicit JOIN condition with ON?

Tags: postgresql, join, execution-plan, postgresql-performance, postgresql-13

Are there any performance differences between

- `JOIN bar USING (foo_id)`
- `JOIN bar ON (foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id)`

I ask this because at least in theory there is more data to project (a duplicate column). When I do `SELECT *` I see more data (having a duplicate column from both copies of `foo_id`), but does that mean more memory is taken during execution? Is it likewise slower to create a result set that is larger, even if it gets reduced later? Or does this all get handled in the planner?

Answer (score 1):

Note, regardless of the results below, it's certainly a lot cleaner and more terse. But let's see if we can quantify this. We'll create 5 tables for sample data, and run both of the queries, with and without an index.

## Sample Data

However, there is of course a cost of sending duplicate data to the client.

```sql
CREATE TABLE a(a_id, aval)       AS SELECT x,x,x FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
CREATE TABLE b(b_id, a_id, bval) AS SELECT x,x,x FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
CREATE TABLE c(c_id, a_id, cval) AS SELECT x,x,x FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
CREATE TABLE d(d_id, a_id, dval) AS SELECT x,x,x FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
CREATE TABLE e(e_id, a_id, eval) AS SELECT x,x,x FROM generate_series(1,1e6) AS x;
```

## Results

Now we can easily test this using these queries,

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT *
FROM a
  JOIN b USING (a_id)
  JOIN c USING (a_id)
  JOIN d USING (a_id)
  JOIN e USING (a_id);

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT *
FROM a
  JOIN b ON (a.a_id = b.a_id)
  JOIN c ON (a.a_id = c.a_id)
  JOIN d ON (a.a_id = d.a_id)
  JOIN e ON (a.a_id = e.a_id);
```

### Without an Index

In both of the queries I see similar numbers for time, and buffers (shared, read, and write). Because of this I see no point in reducing the complexity by removing `SELECT *`. It's already showing to be equal. One thing to see is that that `USING (a_id)` on that query is actually getting rewritten by the planner,

```
# EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
    SELECT *
    FROM A
      JOIN B USING (a_id)
      JOIN C USING (a_id)
      JOIN D USING (a_id)
      JOIN E USING (a_id);
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=98213.24..233245.13 rows=1000000 width=66) (actual time=1011.872..1322.989 rows=1000000 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   Buffers: shared hit=11940 read=20056, temp read=49152 written=49584
   ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=97213.24..132245.13 rows=416667 width=66) (actual time=989.444..1113.915 rows=333333 loops=3)
         Hash Cond: (a.a_id = c.a_id)
```

You can see the Hash Cond above `Hash Cond: (a.a_id = c.a_id)` at the point the query is executed it's already rewritten by the planner.

### With an Index

Just for fun we can add the index and check it too.

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON a(a_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON b(a_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON c(a_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON d(a_id);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON e(a_id);
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE a;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE b;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE c;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE d;
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE e;
```

We can now rerun the queries above but still no change.

## Network Traffic and `SELECT *`

The only difference you measure is network overhead of sending the duplicate columns with `SELECT *`. Measured with `\timing`

```
-- With `USING (a_id)`
Time: 2479.350 ms (00:02.479)
-- With `ON` ...
Time: 2727.338 ms (00:02.727)
```